# Is it correct that the signature type of a ssh key is unchangable?

Tags: ssh

When generating key pairs using `ssh-keygen`, one can specify the desired signature type by `-t`, like `ssh-keygen -t ssh-rsa`. I wonder, is the signature type of a ssh private key **unchangable**, once the key pairs are created?

If it's changeable, which tool can I utilize to change the signature type? and How?

I am asking this question because one of my old keys uses `ssh-rsa` signature type and now the `ssh-rsa` signature algorithm got deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure your ssh-rsa private key is deprecated? The `ssh-rsa` host key algorithm was, but I've not heard of RSA private keys being deprecated. (See, e.g., https://lwn.net/Articles/821565/)

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is deprecated, that's actually what I meant.

Comment: If that's what you meant, you don't have to change your keys.

Comment: You are right @muru I don't have to change my keys. Now I just curious whether the signature of a private key is changable or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a regular SSH key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, the key will not include any signature at all - it is literally just a RSA key pair and nothing else, just like it has always been. **A SSH key does not have a signature type; a SSH connection has one.**

For such keys, a modern enough version of SSH will automatically use `rsa-sha2-512` or `rsa-sha2-256` signatures when both ends of the connection support the newer signature algorithms. In SSH key authentication, the signatures are transient and are only created for the connection negotiation, and discarded afterwards. Therefore, **no changes to existing RSA keys of SSH are needed** to use the new signatures.

(If you run `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -l`, the output will typically say "SHA256": this means SHA256 algorithm is used to produce *the fingerprint of the key*, which is not stored in the key itself, but calculated on-demand. With `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -l -E md5`, you can calculate an old-style MD5 fingerprint from the same key.)

---

But if you are using centrally-managed *SSH certificates*, i.e. if you have files like `id_rsa-cert.pub`, those will have long-term signatures embedded in them. To get rid of the deprecated signature algorithm, you would need to have the certificate(s) reissued, most likely by your organization's own SSH key certification authority.

You could provide a copy of your existing SSH public key to the certification authority (if they don't already have it archived), and they would run:

```
ssh-keygen -s /path/to/ca_key -I key_id /path/to/user_key.pub
```

just like when originally issuing the certificate in the first place.

That command would generate a new `/path/to/user_key-cert.pub` file, which would, if the CA uses an up-to-date `ssh-keygen`, include the CA's signature using the newer `rsa-sha2-512` algorithm by default.

You would still use the same private key as before, but would need to distribute the reissued certificate (essentially a centrally-certified copy of the public key, with some extra management features like an optional expiration date and a CA-defined `key_id` string that is guaranteed to be logged whenever this certificate is used for authentication).

Of course, the CA can decide whether they'll accept copies of previously certified SSH public keys for reissuing the certificates, or not; they might require you to create a new private key at the same time, but that would be a policy issue, not a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can’t. RSA keys and (let’s say) DSA keys are generated differently. Then a given key-pair for one of these algorithms is not a key-pair for the others.

And if you are worry about the strength of RSA, I guess you should worry about each algorithm which share the same key-pairs.

Then the best you can do is to regenerate key-pair and distribute again the public keys (which you can do through a scp protected by RSA until you switch).